# Vertically rotated Label on all subMenuItems inside MenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I have a Menu in my app, that consists of few MenuItems. I'd like a vertical label on the left side of all the MenuItems. Like this (of course with grey background, pardon my paint skill):
[image: wanted output]

I've tried it this way:

```
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <TextBlock Text="Type1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanOpenFile}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="{Binding SaveFileCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Command="{Binding SaveAsFileCommand}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="{Binding ExitAppCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

But it produces an output like this:

[image: Label menuItem output]

Then I tried it via background image (transparent with just a plain text):

```
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding SelectedObjectResourcePath}"/>
            </MenuItem.Background>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanOpenFile}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="{Binding SaveFileCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Command="{Binding SaveAsFileCommand}"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="{Binding ExitAppCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

But it sets the background for the first menuItem only:
[image: background imageBrush]

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is creating a style or modifying the style to do this. Are you using any styles, did you create them?

Comment: @Joe hey, yes there are pre-made styles in my project, but it's rather long. But there will be the culprit probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using StackPanel (with horizontal orientation) here is the best solution in my opinion. Check this out. You just need to make it look as good as you want :)

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Type1" Margin="-30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <Label.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                        </Label.LayoutTransform>
                    </Label>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanOpenFile}"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="{Binding SaveFileCommand}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Command="{Binding SaveAsFileCommand}"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="{Binding ExitAppCommand}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: Yes, I've this came to my mind too, but the problem is, that only first menuItem shows, and nothing more, like so:
http://i.imgur.com/EgdP1jd.png

Comment: I was able to edit my styles to this degree:
http://i.imgur.com/WKXri3C.png

it still takes all the stuff as one menuitem and therefore making the hovereffect etc. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well I am marking this as an answer anyway, because the difficulties are definitely on my side.

Comment: I feel like Grid might be helpful. I will check it and give you answer ASAP :)